# Screenshot of stage

Tags: flash, actionscript, screenshot

Is it possible to take a screenshot (dump image) of the [Stage](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html) and save it to my web server?

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks. I've clarified the post with that now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
myBitmapData.draw(stage);
```

(actually i'm not sure if you can do a draw() on the stage directly, you might need to do this on whatever is on top of your DisplayList instead)

Then use something like this code: http://henryjones.us/articles/using-the-as3-jpeg-encoder

```
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(myBitmapData);

var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("jpg_encoder_download.php?name=sketch.jpg");
jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");
```

To send it to the server.

Comment: Alternatively, if you need to save the file locally you can use Adobe AIR's [File](http://tinyurl.com/5uqd3tz) object to create the file and the [FileStream](http://tinyurl.com/dxdr7jr) object to [open](http://tinyurl.com/c2mojrw) the file, [write](http://tinyurl.com/c9y9rb5) the [ByteArray](http://tinyurl.com/6em96pq) and save the file.

Comment: The link is broken and the bmp.draw(stage) does not handle the filters