# JavaScript screenshot of in browser flash (client side only)

Tags: javascript, flash, screen-capture

Hi I was needing to capture an image of a flash game using JavaScript. What I have found on this so far is that you can do it by editing the flash game itself as well as using client side code.

Does anyone know how to take a screenshot of a flash game with using client only code that will would on all flash games (so the script does not depend on the code of the game to be configured).

If this cannot be done in JavaScript then can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for any input that anyone has :)

Comment: Is the flash game also your code? Can you modify the code of your flash game?

Comment: No that's why I only want a client side code sorry, I know you can do it if you modify the flash game though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that is not possible in javascript, since there is no screenshot api whatsoever for flash.

Comment: Then how can you do it? (Not JavaScript)

Comment: I'd consider using a native application / browser plugin a user has to install if you really need that screenshot, it might be also possible to have the original flash game in another flash instance which creates the screenshot ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946748/screenshot-of-stage )

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Accepted because of your comment providing an alternative solution :)